# Why are there only 10 plugboard pairs in the enigma?

Tags: enigma

The plugboard provides a new layer of security for the enigma but why can we only swap at most 10 letters? I only found things like "10 was the most common." but why stop there? Isn't adding more going to provide more security?

At first, I thought it was not going to add more complexity at one point, because swapping two letters that have already been swapped by the rotors is not going to change anything. But after a rotor does a single turn, that wouldn't matter anymore.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is just a fixed permutation on the view of the analyzer.

Comment: That's explained in some detail [there](https://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/enigma/i/sb.htm). Suggestion: make an answer out of this material. TLDR: it's a design compromise between security and ease of setup. Functionality in practice takes precedence over security, thus security that works must be convenient.

Comment: Presumably they could only have a maximum of 13

Comment: @user253751 What's your point?

Comment: @fgrieu The number of plugs which maximizes the possible layouts is 11 (which is shown in a table on the [page you linked to](https://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/enigma/i/sb.htm)). Surely you would agree that the difference in hassle between using 10 plugs and 11 is negligible. For that matter the difference between 10 and 13 is also all but meaningless.